# Attendance Log using MS Access or SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I'm working this almost a month but I think I need some help now. I have a time logs below. I'm using MS Access and C#. Please help what select query

```
ID  BADGE   CHECKTIME
-----------------------------
1   1507010 5/31/2018 8:51
1   1507010 5/31/2018 19:52
2   1708004 5/31/2018 6:35
2   1708004 5/31/2018 13:43
3   1708005 5/31/2018 19:23
3   1708005 6/1/2018 8:34
4   1708006 5/31/2018 7:51
4   1708006 6/1/2018 18:34
5   1708007 5/31/2018 19:23
5   1708007 6/1/2018 6:36
6   1708009 5/31/2018 7:11
6   1708009 5/31/2018 7:12
6   1708009 5/31/2018 22:02
6   1708009 5/31/2018 22:03
```

I want to become this.please help. what the best query to get this data.

```
ID  Badge   IN              OUT
--------------------------------------------
1   1507010 5/31/2018 8:51  5/31/2018 13:43
2   1708004 5/31/2018 6:35  5/31/2018 13:43
3   1708005 5/31/2018 19:23 6/1/2018 8:34
4   1708006 5/31/2018 7:51  6/1/2018 18:34
5   1708007 5/31/2018 19:23 6/1/2018 6:36
6   1708009 5/31/2018 7:12  5/31/2018 22:03
```

Comment: What is going on with badge `1708009`, and why is the `IN` time `7:12` when in fact the earliest `IN` time appears to be `7:11` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this situation the person tap the biometrics 2 times. but in the query only gets the latest logs.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag if your question is about Access or SQL-Server.

Comment: @Barmar i'm also using sql server.

Comment: @mr.jm I understand that. But you're not using MySQL, so you shouldn't use that tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should get close to what you want:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Badge,
    MIN(CHECKTIME) AS [IN],
    MAX(CHECKTIME) AS [OUT]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Badge;
```

I have a doubt about your expected output for badge `1708009`, since the earliest check time for that badge is `7:11`, not `7:12`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `row_number()` inside the `subquery` :

```
select id, badge, min(checktime) as in, max(checktime) as out
from (select *,  row_number() over (partition by id, badge, cast(checktime as date), datepart(hh,checktime) 
                                       order by datepart(mm,checktime) desc) seq
      from table 
     ) t
where seq = 1
group by id, badge;
```